# Why am I getting index seek?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I am running below query and as it's returning almost all records from the table, it should be using index scan not seek. Anyone, please explain why it's using seek not a scan.

```
DROP TABLE tblPlanDiff
GO
CREATE TABLE tblPlanDiff(Sno int identity,Col_1 int,Col_2 int)
GO
DECLARE @i int=1
WHILE(@i<=200000)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO tblPlanDiff values(@i*2,@i*3)
COMMIT TRAN
SET @i+=1

END
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_Sno on tblplandiff(Sno ASC)
GO
CREATE INDEX ix_Col1_Col2 on tblplandiff(Col_1) INCLUDE(Col_2)
GO
SELECT sno,col_1,col_2 FROM tblPlanDiff
WHERE col_1>2
```

Comment: First of all - you should **be happy** to get index seeks! Those are preferable! Secondly: your clustered key is `Sno` and your index `ix_Col1_Col2` will have all three columns that your query needs - so the query optimizer will use that index to get the answer for your query. And obviously, it figured that doing a series of seeks was more efficient than doing an index scan. Don't worry - be happy!

Comment: Seek is better than scan.  Don't worry, be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an index on `Col_1`, it is able to Seek within that index to a point where `Col_1` values are greater than two. Just because it's doing a Seek doesn't mean that it's not seeking MANY rows.

If you see a Scan, that means it is starting at the beginning of the index and scanning from there. In a sense, an Index Seek may still "scan"; it's just starting from a precise location in the index.

Either way, why are you desiring a Scan over a Seek?

Comment: does"Starting from the beginning of the index" means from the first record in the index? also, I do know that in case of seek..the qualified rows are scanned..

Comment: Yes, [index scan is from first page to last page](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/).

Comment: from the blog "Thus, a scan is an efficient strategy if the table is small or if most of the rows qualify for the predicate." why not in this case? and what If I need to purposely do a scan apart from using a query hint.

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in my comment: **why are you worried about getting an index seek?**

Your index `ix_Col1_Col2` on `Col_1` includes `Col_2` as an included column, and also includes `Sno` from the clustered index - so it contains all three columns that you need to satisfy your query.

So in the end, the query optimizer makes a choice on how to approach this query - and it seems to have preferred an index seek - I don't see any problem with that at all.

When running this query on my SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition, I have these perf values:

```
Table 'tblPlanDiff'. 
Scan count 1, logical reads 797, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 499, 

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 855 ms.
```

When I run the same query with the `WITH (FORCESCAN)` query hint, I get:

```
Table 'tblPlanDiff'. 
Scan count 1, logical reads 797, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 499, 

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 78 ms,  elapsed time = 852 ms.
```

So quite obviously, there's hardly any difference between the two - and there might have been a tiny detail that made the query optimizer prefer the index seek over the scan. Not sure why - but I don't seen any issue or problem with that. Do you?

Comment: I was reading about index scan and seeks and I decided to test them. As many blogs on internet said that scan occurs when query returns all of table rows and seeks occur when query returns fewer rows based on the filter criteria. How can I get an index scan in this case then?

Comment: @user1526100: use `SELECT * FROM ....`  and you're almost guaranteed to get an index scan

Comment: I still got an index seek .. looks like I won't get a scan in this unless I remove the where clause..

Comment: Or just add `... FROM tblPlanDiff WITH (FORCESCAN) ....` and you'll have your scan